# what is the difference between clone method or copy of one arrayList to another arrayList in java ? both gives the same hashCode pls check below code

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> c1= new ArrayList<String>();
    c1.add("Red");
    c1.add("Green");
    c1.add("Black");
    c1.add("White");
    c1.add("Pink");

    System.out.println("Original array list: " + c1);
    ArrayList<String> newc1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    newc1 = (ArrayList<String>) c1.clone();
    
    System.out.println("Cloned array list: " + newc1);
    
    ArrayList<String> c2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    c2.addAll(c1);
    
         
    System.out.println(c1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(newc1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(c2.hashCode());
    
 
}
```

what is the difference between clone method or copy of one arrayList to another arrayList in java ? both gives the same hashCode pls check below code.

Comment: `clone()` was, generally speaking, a mistake and shouldn't be used. The `List` interface [requires a specific formula for `hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--) and will be the same even if you use a `LinkedList` or something else.

Comment: `(ArrayList<String>) c1.clone();` is an unsafe cast.  The compiler cannot guarantee reliable behavior of generics that result from an unsafe cast.  That alone is a good reason to avoid cloning a collection.

Comment: Please don't use clone() except then copy of simple 1D arrays

Comment: If the object is an instance of a subclass of `ArrayList`, the `clone()` method will produce an instance of that subclass—though not necessarily a correctly working one. Which leads the the conclusion already posted by the previous commenter. Better avoid using `clone()` (and also avoid making subclasses of `ArrayList`, there’s the “prefer delegation over inheritance” recommendation).

Answer (score 0):

clone() is the function of the Obejct class, which is a kind of shallow copy, which means that it just copys the address of the object.

hashcode() of a list depends on the elements of the list, so if these list contains the same elements, they will have the same result value of hashcode(), unless you overwrite hashcode() by yourself.